# Python: csv_writer writing 1 number in separate cells problem

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping

I have built a simple webscraper that gets the population from a website given the city name. The output is in the string format:
"City, State | Data USA
Population"

For example, running print(search.text) for New Smyrna Beach it returns the string:

New Smyrna Beach, FL | Data USA
25,770

I want the program to write this in a csv file but the number is being separated in multiple columns when I would like it in one cell. It appears the "New Smyrna Beach, FL | Data USA" is not being writed at all, how come?

Here is my code for the csv writing:

```
import csv
with open('population.csv', 'w') as f:
   thewriter = csv.writer(f)
   thewriter.writerow(search.text)
```

And here is my output in the CSV file.

2|  5|  ,|  7|  7|  0|
(each | denotes a new column)
I want the csv file to write 25,770 in one cell just like that. Also not required but would be useful if the program actually wrote the city name as well. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is your expected result simply `city, population`?

Comment: Yes! Mainly I want the number in one cell but that format would be perfect as well

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can't split on `,` or   due to your population containing a comma and your city name containing spaces. We could do this a few ways.

1. Perform two splits on both `,` and   and returning the correct position with a list `slice`
2. Use regex to extract the information

---

**Splitting**

```
search = 'New Smyrna Beach, FL | Data USA 25,770'
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([search.split(',')[0], search.split(' ')[-1]])
```

---

**Regex**

```
import re

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    city = re.match(r'^([^,]*)', search).group(0)
    population = re.findall(r'(\d+,\d+)', search)[0]

    writer.writerow([city, population])
```

---

**Output**

[image]